# Retrieving invalid index to scalar variable error while accessing array content

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am running the below code, I retrieve an error.

```
def partition():

  TE = m_latency()
  TC = c_latency()
  TU = []
  for k in range(1, 10):
    TU = output(k)
    print(TU)
  N = 9
  SUMS = [0] * N
  for j in range(N):
    for i in range(1, j + 1):
        SUMS[j] += TE[i]
    for k in range(j - 1, N + 1):
        SUMS[j] += TC[k]
    SUMS[j] += TU[j]
  return min(SUMS)
```

When I run the above code, I get the below error.

```
 SUMS[j] += TU[j] IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable
```

Comment: `TU` is not an array. Perhaps `TU = output(k)` should be `TU.append(output(k))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `TU = output(k)`, you *replace* the TU variable by whatever `output()` returns, it is not an array/list anymore.

You can use `TU[k]` in your loop instead :

```py
def partition():

  TE = m_latency()
  TC = c_latency()
  TU = []
  for k in range(1, 10):
    TU[k] = output(k)
    print(TU[k])
  N = 9
  SUMS = [0] * N
  for j in range(N):
    for i in range(1, j + 1):
        SUMS[j] += TE[i]
    for k in range(j - 1, N + 1):
        SUMS[j] += TC[k]
    SUMS[j] += TU[j]
  return min(SUMS)
```